# An efficient way to buffer HD video real-time without maxing out memory

Tags: c++, c, qt, opencv, computer-vision

I am writing a program that involves real-time processing of video from a network camera using OpenCV. I want to be able to capture (at any time during processing) previous images (e.g. say ten seconds worth) and save to a video file.

I am currently doing this using a **queue** as a buffer (to push 'cv::Mat' data) but this is obviously not efficient as a few seconds worth of images soon uses up all the PC memory. I tried compressing images using 'cv::imencode' but that doesn't make much difference using PNG, I need a solution that uses **hard-drive memory** and efficient for real-time operation.

Can anyone suggest a very simple and efficient solution?

EDIT:

Just so that everyone understands what I'm doing at the moment; here's the code for a 10 second buffer:

```
void run()
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    int buffer_lenght = 10;     // in seconds
    int wait = 1000.0/fps;
    QTime time;


    forever{
        time.restart();
        cv::mat image;
        bool read = cap.read(image);

        if(!read)
            break;

        bool locked = _mutex.tryLock(10);

        if(locked){
            if(image.data){
                _buffer.push(image);

                if((int)_buffer.size() > (fps*buffer_lenght))
                    _buffer.pop();
            }
            _mutex.unlock();
        }

        int time_taken = time.elapsed();
        if(time_taken<wait)
            msleep(wait-time_taken);

    }

    cap.release();
}
```

`queue<cv::Mat> _buffer` and `QMutex _mutex` are global variables. If you're familiar with QT, signals and slots etc, I've got a slot that grabs the buffer and saves it as a video using cv::VideoWriter.

EDIT:
I think the ideal solution will be for my `queue<cv::Mat> _buffer` to use **hard-drive memory** rather than **pc memory**. Not sure on which planet this is possible? :/

Comment: which solution did you choose? I would suggest `imencode` to memory as jpg if thats not too slow.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest looking into real-time compression with [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) or similar. x264 is regularly used for [real-time encoding](http://x264dev.multimedia.cx/archives/249) of video streams and, with the right settings, can encode multiple streams or a 1080p video stream in a moderately powered processor.
I suggest asking in [doom9's forum](http://forum.doom9.org) or similar forums.

x264 is a free h.264 encoder which can achieve 100:1 or better (vs raw) compression. The output of x264 can be stored in your memory queue with much greater efficiency than uncompressed (or losslessly compressed) video.

Comment: Please have a look at my edit. I don't see how x264 can work because it is for video?

Comment: x264 is still happy with still images. Each would be considered one frame of video. If the images were captured more than a few tenths of a second apart, the difference between images might be too great for good compression.
Aside from that, you can always save them as JPEG (which would still be larger than x264). JPEG is much more efficient for camera captures than PNG.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

One thing you can do is store images to the hard disk using `imwrite` and update their filenames to the queue. When the queue is full, delete images as you pop filenames.
In your video writing slot, load the images as they are popped from the queue and write them to your `VideoWriter` instance

---

You mentioned you needed to use **Hard Drive Memory**

In that case, consider using the *OpenCV HighGUI VideoWriter*. You can create an instance of VideoWriter as below:

```
VideoWriter record("RobotVideo.avi", CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X'), 
    30, frame.size(), true);
```

And write image captures to in as below:

```
record.write(image);
```

Find the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter-videowriter) and the [sample program](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/documentation/cpp/highgui/VideoWriter) on the website.

Comment: That won't work because I can only add images to record, I can't remove images previously added images. I need a solution where the buffer holds- for example the last ten seconds worth of images at any instant in time.

Comment: in that case, one thing you can do is store images to the hard disk using `imwrite` and update their filenames to the queue... when the queue is full delete images as you pop filenames... also... in your video writing slot, load the images as they are popped from the queue and write them to `VideoWriter`... hope this helps... :-)